# How to get .hasOwnProperty for Generic types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Lets say I have a generic class which stores items in an array items of type T.  If type T has a property index, I would like to set the index property of the T instance to the position of the item in the array.

Something like this:

```
class TList<T> {
    _list : T[];

    add(item : T) {
        this._list.push(item);
        if (item.hasOwnProperty("index")) {
            item.index = this._list.length-1;
        }
    }

    get list() : T[] {
        return this._list;
    }
    constructor() {
        this._list=[];
    }
}
```

Right now, I get a compiler error on the if statement `if (item.hasOwnProperty("index"))`
that generic type T doesn't have a hasOwnProperty method.

What would be the workaround, other than limiting T to only types which have an index property (which I don't want to do).

Comment: You'd need to limit `T` to types that have a `hasOwnProperty` method (e.g., `Object`s).

Comment: I would be really irritated if I were using your list.

Comment: AH: Yeah, I would be irritated too.  It's just an example of the problem .  It doesn't make a lot of sense to me that you could replace T with 'any' and the code would work as expected.  If hasProperty works on 'any' it seems like it should work on T.

Comment: Heretic, i think you are missing the point, which is not to limit the objects added but to interrogate them.

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee that this class can operate on its items, typescript needs to enforce that the two properties you expect are present: `hasOwnProperty` and `index`. Typescript is telling you that a type without those properties could be passed in, and your function would fail.

`hasOwnProperty` is provided by `Object.prototype`, so you get that when you constrain `T` to an object type. But `index` is part of your own implementation here. So you need to declare that explicitly.

That means you can constrain `T` like so, and it all works like you expect.

```
class TList<T extends { index?: number }> { ... }
```

You'd then use it with something like:

```
interface TItem {
  name: string
  index?: number
}

const list = new TList<TItem>()
list.add({ name: 'a' })
list.add({ name: 'a', index: 123456 })
console.log(list.list) // [{ name: 'a'}, { name: 'b', index; 1 }]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqAyBLCAXAPLaBTAHirAdgCYwDe0ixuA-AFzQECuAtgEZYBO0AvgHzSkAUNBHQA+iGQpo9WAG0AugG5Bw0WCJEAFInzMZcAJQC1o0SgAWyAHQSp1gA6MIFnXsMqzZxADNobrGZrC0gAeQB3AgAFDgB7B04UAE8tACJKIlxUw2MhL3yKPWsM3GgAXmhLGztUaxBCAHNLAFoARk8C7lMeVTMGrGlJVC1jWUUTAugOAcYOAkqrCFshlA6RLrNgWIJUDkZgFFiOEYmCqqWalDLFNZ6uwUp8Dh8wYCw4AEk9U4IwZix6LtKA01CUcHQGCx2BxBPctjtBlJygwsOE4EhUBgvoFeCNBCtrBptORfv96AByMDkniGfH2IlaEl-AHQSnkgA0FCoOHorQATABmGmCeEQWL1OqxBpaAkrYwAenl0DkTLJrKp3E5qpZ5NYHK5mRwSmgrR4CiAA)

Comment: That isn't the purpose of the code.  The purpose of the code is "if the item passed has an index property, set it to the index within the array".  If it doesn't have an index property, do nothing.

Comment: Typescript still needs to be aware that the `index` property is accessible, so it has to be declared somewhere. If post how you intend to use this class I can probably give you better advice.

Comment: See the answer I posted, which answers the question I posted:  'If type T has a property index, I would like to set the index property of the T instance to the position of the item in the array.'  Your suggestion would not permit  object which don't have an index property to  be added to the list, which is not the design goal.

Comment: @user1023110 You shouldn't be adding a property to an object that isn't supposed to exist on that objects type. That means typescript is no longer keeping that area of the code type safe. Instead, it's far better to actually strongly type everything so typescript can verify the types in every single line of code.

Comment: Im sorry I don't agree. Statement's like "you shouldn't" and "its far better" absent of context of the way `any` is being used just expresses a  preference not a best practice. If the designers saw no purpose for `any` or `hasOwnProperty` I suppose they wouldn't have included in the language.  Of course you shouldn't use `any` & `as Foo` haphazardly as a cheat around the typesystem, but I believe 'any' is suited cases where type is indeterminate at compile time because generics are being used. Your solve "strongly type everything" would eliminates generics altogether and hobble the language.

Comment: Generics are strongly typed, ‘any’ is not. I’m obviously not going to win you over here, but in my work I would definitely fail a code review that used any when it wasn’t required.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find such a package on npm and I thought it would be nice to create one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-has-own-property. I think it will help someone :)

Answer (score -1):

Casting item to 'any' solves the problem since any supports hasOwnProperty.

```
class TList<T> {
    _list : T[];

    add(item : T) {
        this._list.push(item);
        if ((item as any).hasOwnProperty("index")) {
            (item as any).index = this._list.length-1;
        }
    }

    get list() {
        return this._list;
    }
    constructor() {
        this._list=[];
    }
}
```

Comment: Casting to `any` is usually bad idea without a good reason, as you are telling Typescript not to typecheck anything when you do that. It lets you do anything with `any`.

Comment: Yes, I think we all know that that is true, the language doesn't support inquiring of generic parameters, even properties that every type in typescript suppots (such as hasOwnProperty) as evidenced that any supports it.  When the language doen't support things that it 'should' be able to do, you have to resort to workarounds.  In this case, the object is cast solely for the purpose of determining whether the object supports the index property, and then it only access a property the object is known to have.